# angular 2 want to define an array inside the object so that i can push some value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to define array inside the object I am using dot notation 
but it is always showing undefined

my HTML code

```
<mat-checkbox  *ngFor="let q1 of question.checkboxes;" (change)="checkboxSelected(q1,question,$event)"> {{q1.name}} </mat-checkbox>
```

my ts code

```
checkboxSelected(selected,obj,event){obj.box.push('somecondition') }
```

it is showing an error that

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize `obj.box`.

Comment: sorry didn't get @HassanImam

Comment: You need to initialize `obj.box` with empty array, before you start pushing element in them

Comment: have  tried that but still i can't push @HassanImam

Comment: thank you so much it worked finally  @HassanImam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if property "box" exists inside your object "question".

If it exists, check whether it is initialized properly i.e question.box = []

Comment: it does not exists because i am binding it dynamically

Comment: Try `question.prototype.box = []` for initialization before pushing the **first** element.